# DOM PDF no me muestra la imagen, me muestra un Espacio en BLANCO

Tags: php, ajax, pdf, dompdf, libreria

```
// BLOQUE DE PRUEBA INICIO
$html ='<html>
        <body>
          <h1>Mi Documento PDF</h1>
          <img src="img/descarga.png" alt="Mi imagen" /> // RUTA DE LA IMAGEN
          <p>Otro contenido del PDF...</p>
        </body>
        </html>';
        
// BLOQUE DE PRUEBA FIN
```

Este bloque es para generar el pdf.

La ruta de mi archivo se encuentra dentro de la carpeta donde esta el servidor `xampp`

Esta es la salida de mi código, se observa que ese muestra el espacio en blanco y no me muestra la imagen.
[image: imagen]

Comment: ¿Verificaste que la ruta de la imagen es correcta?, puede que sea por falta de algunos ajustes para que se visualice la imagen, quizás te ayude [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153139/dompdf-remote-image-is-not-displaying-in-pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el source de la imagen, debe quedar algo así:

```
<img src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/Proyecto/ruta/de_la/imagen.png">
```